# Asset publisher visibility on no result found LR6.0.6

Tags: liferay-6

We are working with LR6.0.6 asset publisher. If we configure an asset publisher with a category that doesn't contain any asset, then the asset publisher is hidden if we toggle off from the dockbar.
We would like to show the asset publisher with the default message, as we are not showing the dockbar to the users.

[image: sample hidden asset publisher]

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In \html\portlet\asset_publisher\init.jsp file make changes[using liferay-hook] for line

```
boolean showPortletWithNoResults = false;
```

And make it

```
boolean showPortletWithNoResults = true;
```

This would solve your issue.

By this you would be able to see message "There are no results." .